# Links not being drawn on force layout d3

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, force-layout

I am trying to create a forced layout with `react` and `d3`. I am stuck at why my links are not being created. The clicks and drags are not working as well, but that is another issue for now (I would be happy if it was solved on this very thread as well). I basically copy-pasted the code for forced layout from [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) and converted it to an ugly `React15` code. My code looks like this

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import d3 from "d3";
import * as force from "d3-force";
import * as selection from "d3-selection";
import * as drag from "d3-drag";

const style = {
  height: "200px",
  width: "415px",
  // padding: '15px',
  boxShadow: "grey 0px 0px 3px 1px",
  margin: "5px",
  paddingLeft: "15px",
  marginRight: "20px"
};

export default class ForcedGraph extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      graphData: this.props.nodeLinkObject || {
        nodes: [
          { id: "node1", group: 1 },
          { id: "node2", group: 2 },
          { id: "node3", group: 3 },
          { id: "node4", group: 2 },
          { id: "node5", group: 3 },
          { id: "node6", group: 3 }
        ],
        links: [
          { source: "node1", target: "node2", value: 5 },
          { source: "node1", target: "node4", value: 10 },
          { source: "node2", target: "node3", value: 12 },
          { source: "node4", target: "node5", value: 9 },
          { source: "node4", target: "node6", value: 3 }
        ]
      }
    };
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    // Prevents component re-rendering
    return false;
  }

  setRef = component => {
    // D3 Code to create the chart
    // using this._rootNode as container
    const svg = component;
    const width = 960;
    const height = 600;
    const simulation = force
      .forceSimulation()
      .force("link", force.forceLink().id(d => d.id))
      .force("charge", force.forceManyBody())
      .force("center", force.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

    const graph = this.state.graphData;
    this.drawGraph(svg, graph, simulation);
  };

  dragstarted = (d, simulation) => {
    if (!selection.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  };

  dragged = d => {
    d.fx = selection.event.x;
    d.fy = selection.event.y;
  };

  dragended = (d, simulation) => {
    if (!selection.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  };

  drawGraph = (svg, graph, simulation) => {
    const colorMap = {
      "1": "red",
      "2": "blue",
      "3": "green"
    };

    const node = selection
      .select(svg)
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 10)
      .attr("fill", d => colorMap[d.group])
      .attr("transform", "translate(200,100)")
      .call(
        drag
          .drag()
          .on("start", d => this.dragstarted(d, simulation))
          .on("drag", d => this.dragged(d))
          .on("end", d => this.dragended(d, simulation))
      );

    const link = selection
      .select(svg)
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter()
      .append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", d => Math.sqrt(d.value))
      .attr("fill", "red")
      .attr("transform", "translate(200,100)");

    node.append("title").text(d => d.id);

    simulation.nodes(graph.nodes).on("tick", this.ticked(link, node));
    simulation.force("link").links(graph.links);
  };

  ticked = (link, node) => {
    node.attr("cx", d => d.x * 5).attr("cy", d => d.y * 5);
    link
      .attr("x1", d => d.source.x * 5)
      .attr("y1", d => d.source.y * 5)
      .attr("x2", d => d.target.x * 5)
      .attr("y2", d => d.target.y * 5);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="columns large-12 small-12 medium-12" style={style}>
        <svg width="960" height="600" ref={this.setRef} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ForcedGraph.propTypes = {
  nodeLinkObject: PropTypes.shape({
    nodes: PropTypes.arrayOf(
      PropTypes.shape({
        id: PropTypes.string,
        group: PropTypes.number
      })
    ),
    links: PropTypes.arrayOf(
      PropTypes.shape({
        source: PropTypes.string,
        target: PropTypes.string,
        value: PropTypes.number
      })
    )
  }).isRequired
};

render(<ForcedGraph />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

The main problem here is that my links are not getting a `x` and `y` properties. That much I figured out by console logging my `this.ticked` method.

```
  ticked = (link, node) => {
    node.attr("cx", d => d.x * 5).attr("cy", d => d.y * 5);
    link
      .attr("x1", d => {
        console.log(d, d.source);
        return d.source.x * 5;
      })
      .attr("y1", d => d.source.y * 5)
      .attr("x2", d => d.target.x * 5)
      .attr("y2", d => d.target.y * 5);
  };
```

What I found on console logging as very peculiar.

[image]

The object did have a source.x attribute, but it was not there at the time of access. So somehow , the object was mutated after I had accessed it. Or may be something else.

I have replicated my issue [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/o4kzrr6jj5)

I would be so happy if this was resolved. It fried my brain the whole day.

I solved the issue with the selected answer and the drags by importing separately from the modules (or atleast I think that is what changed everything)

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {forceSimulation, forceLink, forceManyBody, forceCenter} from 'd3-force';
import {select} from 'd3-selection';
import {drag} from 'd3-drag';



export default class ForcedGraph extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      graphData: this.props.nodeLinkObject || {
        nodes: [
          {id: 'node1', group: 1},
          {id: 'node2', group: 2},
          {id: 'node3', group: 3},
          {id: 'node4', group: 2},
          {id: 'node5', group: 3},
          {id: 'node6', group: 3},
        ],
        links: [
          {source: 'node1', target: 'node2', value: 5},
          {source: 'node1', target: 'node4', value: 10},
          {source: 'node2', target: 'node3', value: 12},
          {source: 'node4', target: 'node5', value: 9},
          {source: 'node4', target: 'node6', value: 3},
        ],
      },
    };
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    // Prevents component re-rendering
    return false;
  }

  setRef = component => {
    // D3 Code to create the chart
    // using this._rootNode as container
    const svg = component;
    const width = 415;
    const height = 200;
    const simulation = forceSimulation()
      .force('link', forceLink().id(d => d.id))
      .force('charge', forceManyBody())
      .force('center', forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

    const graph = this.state.graphData;
    this.drawGraph(svg, graph, simulation);
  };

  dragstarted = (simulation, d) => {
    if (!getEvent().active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  };

  dragged = d => {
    d.fx = getEvent().x;
    d.fy = getEvent().y;
  };

  dragended = (simulation, d) => {
    if (!getEvent().active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  };

  drawGraph = (svg, graph, simulation) => {
    const colorMap = {
      '1': 'red',
      '2': 'blue',
      '3': 'green',
    };

    const node = select(svg)
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'nodes')
      .selectAll('circle')
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('r', 10)
      .attr('fill', d => colorMap[d.group])
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
      .call(
        drag()
          .on('start', d => this.dragstarted(simulation, d))
          .on('drag', d => this.dragged(d))
          .on('end', d => this.dragended(simulation, d))
      );

    const link = select(svg)
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'links')
      .selectAll('line')
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter()
      .append('line')
      .attr('stroke-width', d => Math.sqrt(d.value))
      .attr('style', 'stroke: #999; stroke-opacity: 0.6;')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)');

    node.append('title').text(d => d.id);

    simulation.nodes(graph.nodes).on('tick', () => this.ticked(link, node));
    simulation.force('link').links(graph.links);
  };

  ticked = (link, node) => {
    node.attr('cx', d => d.x).attr('cy', d => d.y);
    link
      .attr('x1', d => d.source.x)
      .attr('y1', d => d.source.y)
      .attr('x2', d => d.target.x)
      .attr('y2', d => d.target.y);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="column large-12 medium-12 small-12" style={style}>
        <svg width="415" height="200" ref={this.setRef} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `.on('tick', eventListener)` (https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#simulation_on) is expecting a function as its second parameter. In your case, your second parameter is `this.ticked(link, node)`, which would be invoked once and return *undefined*. You could either have ticked return a function:

```
ticked = (link, node) => { //needs to return function
  return () => {  
    node.attr("cx", d => d.x * 5).attr("cy", d => d.y * 5);
    link
      .attr("x1", d => {
        console.log(d, d.source);
        return d.source.x * 5;
      })
      .attr("y1", d => d.source.y * 5)
      .attr("x2", d => d.target.x * 5)
      .attr("y2", d => d.target.y * 5);
  }
};
```

Or, probably cleaner and consistent with what you've done elsewhere - your second parameter could be an arrow function that calls ticked:

```
simulation.nodes(graph.nodes).on("tick", () => this.ticked(link, node));
```

Also, you will probably want to set the stroke on your links (we don't yet appear to have any css for the .links class):

```
const link = selection
      .select(svg)
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter()
      .append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", d => Math.sqrt(d.value))
      .attr("style", "stroke: #ff0000; stroke-opacity: 0.6;")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");
```

Regarding mouse event listeners, it looks like there was a problem with modular d3 imports working within code sandbox - d3Drag didn't look like it was getting injected with the right instance of d3Selection. Using the latest stand alone version of d3, drag handling seems to work out as expected.

Slightly modified working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/xvr5orqj4o

Comment: Making the tick function return a function in itself did work. I made my drags to work as well. But I have no idea how I did it. I have edited my question with the solution to my problem. But then again, it will be up for others to check the differences between the solutions.